# Pointer redefinition error

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

I wrote the following code for LCD interfacing of the 8051 microcontroller using strings and pointers. I declared two strings namely str1 and str2 and pointers ptr1 and ptr2 respectively. When I initiliasied both the pointers to the starting of the strings, I got the error C231 saying that 'ptr1' : redefinition and same for ptr2. Following is the code:

```
#include<reg51.h>
char str1[]="abcd";
char str2[]="efgh";
int i;
char *ptr1;
ptr1=&str1[0];
char *ptr2;
ptr2=&str2[0];
sbit rs=P1^0;
sbit wr=P1^1;
sbit en=P1^2;
void delay()
{
   int i,j;
   for(i=0;i<100;i++)
   for(j=0;j<1275;j++);
}
void lcd_inl()
{
   comwrt(0x38);
   comwrt(0x0f);
   comwrt(0x01);
   comwrt(0x81);
}
void datwrt(char)  
{
    P2=ch;
    rs=1;
    wr=0;
    en=1;
    delay();
    en=0; 
}
void comwrt(int)
{
   P2=i;
   rs=0;
   wr=0;
   en=1;
   delay();
   en=0;
}
void main()
{
   P1=0x00;
   P2=0x00;
   lcd_inl();
   delay();
   while(!*ptr1)
   {
       datwrt(*ptr1);
       ptr1++;
   }
    delay();
    while(!*ptr2)
   {
      comwrt(0xc1);
      delay();
      datwrt(*ptr2);
      ptr2++;
   }
   while(1);  
   }
```

Comment: Not enough information.

Comment: The code posted is valid. How is `str` defined?

Comment: strings are defined as: char str1[ ]= "This is it"

Comment: Same for string 2 as: str2[ ]= "now";

Comment: There is no `str1` and `str2` in your code, only `str`.

Comment: @chayan  I see only one problem of the code: neither str1 nor str2 are declared and used in this code snippet.:)

Comment: Code : char str1[ ]="ABCD" ; char str2[ ]="efgh"; char *ptr1; ptr1= &str1[0]; ptr2= &str2[0];

Comment: Please post either the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem, or a complete function. **Edit the question** instead of drip-feeding comments that only cloud the issues.

Comment: The code you posted as a comment has the problem `error: 'ptr2' undeclared ` Please **edit** the code in the question and make sure to post the exact code that causes problems instead of a rewrite.

Comment: Edit posted. All the strings and pointers have been defined

Comment: The error means that you have an earlier declaration of the same variable. Post the whole function definition.

Comment: Your code compiles perfectly when copied into a `main` function.

Comment: There is no other declaration @barmar.

Comment: I vote to close down this question as being *unclear*. It is neither **minimal** nor **complete** nor **verifiable**!

Comment: @chayan Compilers don't lie. If it says you're redefining, there must be another declaration. If these are global variables, maybe it's in a header file. Post the whole code.

Comment: I have posted the whole code. Please let me know the error now.

Comment: Replace the 2 lines `char *ptr1;` and `ptr1=&str1[0];` by a single declaration-assignment. Same for `ptr2`.

Comment: when writing code, the variable names should indicate content or usage (or better, both).   For ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code. 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
ptr1=&str1[0];
```

must be within a function, as must all executable code, apart from initialisation statements incorporated as part of the definition.

So you would need

```
char *ptr1 = str1;
```

**Edit** (from OP's comment) like this:

```
#include<reg51.h>
char str1[]="abcd";
char str2[]="efgh";
int i;
char *ptr1 = str1;
char *ptr2 = str2;
sbit rs=P1^0;
sbit wr=P1^1;
sbit en=P1^2;
```

I have looked in [reg51.h](http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/c51/reg51.h) and there is no `str1` or `str2` or `ptr1` or `ptr2`. So if you are still getting an error, there is something you haven't told us.

Comment: Getting more errors. I'm quitting for now. Maybe I'll ask my professor tomorrow. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please listen. You must post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: Note: With pre C99, `ptr1=&str1[0];` is itself valid as declaration and an initialization of `int ptr1`.  Hence the "redefinition" error.

Comment: @chux but not outside of a function. I simplified `char *ptr1 = &str1[0];` to `char *ptr1 = str1;`

Comment: With pre C99, `ptr1=&str1[0];` _is_ valid outside a function.  Same as effect as `int ptr1=&str1[0];`.  Note that the error is a "redefinition" one.

Comment: Where does `int ptr1` come from?